# Numerical input to a range

Tags: python, input, range

In Python I would like to take a numerical value input and put it into a range. The goal is to iterate a question multiple times based on the number entered in the original input.  What confuses me is that the the original input value changes so I don’t know how to make the range argument  value change with original
Input.

```
Number =input(“enter a number”)

for I in range(10):
      Color=input(“enter an color”)  #this input is iterated multiple times based on the number input. I dont know how make range change it’s value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the number your user has entered, convert it to an `int`, and then use that as your input to `range`:

```
Number = input(“enter a number”)
n = int(Number)

for I in range(n):
      Color=input(“enter an color”)
```

You need to do the `int` conversion because user input is stored as a string, however `range` expects an `int`. Unfortunately if the user enters something that can't be converted to an `int`, the conversion will fail and your program will crash. You could handle this by testing that the conversion succeeds and notifying your user otherwise:

```
while(True):
    Number = input(“enter a number”)
    try:
        n = int(Number)
    except:
        print("You did not enter a valid number!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
num = int (input(“Enter a number:”) )

for I in range(num):
      Color=input(“enter an color:”)

>>>Enter a number:4
enter a color:red
enter a color:green
enter a color:blue
enter a color:brown
```

> This is achieved by supplying the value `num` to python's [range function](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/).

Say you want to test this:

```
num = 4
for i in range(num): #Notice num being the input of range
    print(i,)
>>>0,1,2,3
```

This implies that the `range(num)` function starts from **0** and stops at **`num-1`**.

The initial output can be changed by supplying it:

```
 num = 4
    for i in range(2,num): #Notice 2 and num being the initial and final endpoint respectively.
        print(i,)
    >>>2,3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this...

```
# assuming you're writing this in python2.7, otherwise, input() is fine
number = raw_input('enter a number: ') # allow user to input a number
for i in range(int(number)): # cast the string to an integer, and do the following the requested number of times...
    color = raw_input('enter a color: ')
```

Be careful with the `input()` function if you're using python 2.7:

[What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

#### For Completeness

Others have pointed out that the original could throw an error, so why not add some safety?

```
number = raw_input('enter a number: ')
try:
    for i in range(int(number)):
        color = raw_input('enter a color: ')
except Exception as exc:
    print exc, "You must enter a valid integer"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to Python!